# CMD line BATCH file - locating most recent file "LIKE" and renaming it

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I got something that has been given me some problems for a little while. I have a list of reports that are `.csv` files. The way they are organized is:

> ```
> Call Details Report_1448937644342.csv
> Call Details Report_1449662976507.csv
> Call Details Report_1450293169999.csv
> Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1448937621469.csv
> Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1449662916869.csv
> Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1450293146194.csv
> Location Detail Report_1448937658179.csv
> Location Detail Report_1449662949955.csv
> Location Detail Report_1450293201330.csv
> Location Summary Report_1448937672801.csv
> Location Summary Report_1449662994508.csv
> Location Summary Report_1450293231606.csv
> StartStop (1).csv
> StartStop (2).csv
> StartStop (3).csv
> StartStop.csv
> Sensor (1).csv
> Sensor (2).csv
> Sensor (3).csv
> ```

So what I would need is something that I can copy the most recent of each report to a different directory while renaming it without the spaces or numbers (CallDetailsReport, IntialCallPricingByArchiveReport, etc.). So if I would run the batch file now it would take that directory of files, find Most recent of each report, copy and rename it to another directory.

I have tried to use the `FOR` command, but have had very little luck, the biggest problem I have is the number after the `_` varies greatly, but it is always greater. I also thought that maybe I could narrow it down by the most recent files, but the endings always being different is kind of messing me up. I am hoping you guys can help.

I got this so far that gives me a list, but does not narrow it down to the most recent.

```
FOR %%G IN (Report1*.csv ) do @echo %%G
```

Comment: Could we assume that the higher numbers are also the newest files? Meaning it has a newer create date?

Comment: The last reports do not comply with the description, there are no `_` characters in their names; I assume the number within `()` is the one to use, but what about `StartStop.csv` then? can it be seen as `StartStop (0).csv` for determination of the greatest number, which I assume is the most recent one??

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv" '
  ) DO (
 IF "%%b" neq "" IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%a" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a %%b" "%destdir%\%%a" >nul
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Read the source directory in basic form without directorynames and in reverse-date order so the latest files matching the mask appear first. Split the filename into two using the space as a separator. If the second part is not empty (ie the space exists) test for the presence of a file `thefirstpart` in the destination directory and perform the copy if it doesn't exist - consequently it will be copied from the first (latest) file found and not be overwritten.

Adjustments to suit your actual requirement would be in your court.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv" '
  ) DO (
 IF "%%b" equ "" (
  FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%j IN ("%%a") DO (
   IF "%%k" neq "" IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%j" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%j" 
  )
 ) ELSE (
  IF NOT EXIST "%destdir%\%%a" COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a_%%b" "%destdir%\%%a" 
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Revision to suit realistic filenames.

Comment: I guess I should have given you guys some more information about exactly how the files are laid out. I updated the main question to give a more accurate listing.  There are 2 different report types. On one the numbers are separated by a "_" and on the other the number is in "( )". I guess I am overthinking things that makes me not understand exactly how to make this work... I will know better next time.. Sorry Guys.

Answer (score 0):

#### Original Answer (based on the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561732/2))

Assuming that the greatest numbers denote the most recent items, the following batch script does what you are looking for:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set up source and destination directories here:
set "SOURCE=D:\source"
set "DESTIN=D:\destin"

for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=._ " %%I in ('
    2^> nul dir /B /A:-D "%SOURCE%\*.csv" ^| ^
    findstr /I /R /C:"^Report[0-9][0-9]* Number_[0-9][0-9]*.csv$"
') do (
    set "REPORT=%%I"
    set "REPORT=0000000!REPORT:*Report=!"
    set "NUMBER=0000000%%K"
    set "ITEM-!REPORT:~-8!=%%I.%%L"
    set "ITEMS-!REPORT:~-8!-!NUMBER:~-8!=%%I %%J_%%K.%%L"
)
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=-=" %%I in ('
    2^> nul set ITEM-
') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%X in ('
        2^> nul set ITEMS-%%I-
    ') do (
        set "RECENT=%%X"
    )
    > nul copy /Y /B "%SOURCE%\!RECENT!" "%DESTIN%\%%J"
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Basically this approach builds up array-like variables `ITEM-` and `ITEMS-` that hold the numbers in the file names padded with leading zeros to consist of 8 digits, then use `set` to sort the items alphabetically and retrieve the most recent item. Because of the padding, alphabetic sorting results in the same order as alphanumeric sorting.

Both of these variables are set up in the first `for /F` loop, which enumerates all the applicable items using `dir /B /A:-D "*.csv" | findstr /I /R /C:"^Report[0-9][0-9]* Number_[0-9][0-9]*.csv$"`. `findstr` is used to filter the files, because `dir` cannot so that in the same grade of detail. The variable names contain the zero-padded numbers for proper sorting. The variable values are the original file names (`ITEMS-`) and the new file names (`ITEM-`).

The second `for /F` loop parses the output of `set ITEM-`, which walks through all the first numbers after the word `Report`. This loop nests another one, iterating through the output of `set ITEMS-`, which holds both numbers in the file names. The inner loop stores the current item in variable `RECENT` and overwrites its value each time. Due to the sort order, the greatest number and therefore the most recent item is stored in `RECENT`. The outer loop is then actually copying the relative file.

Relying on the sample files you provided, the two arrays will hold the following data:

**`ITEM-` (sorted):**

> ```
> ITEM-00000001=Report1.csv
> ITEM-00000002=Report2.csv
> ITEM-00000003=Report3.csv
> ```

**`ITEMS-` (sorted):**

> ```
> ITEMS-00000001-00000123=Report1 Number_123.csv
> ITEMS-00000001-00000126=Report1 Number_126.csv
> ITEMS-00000001-00000133=Report1 Number_133.csv
> ITEMS-00000002-00000123=Report2 Number_123.csv
> ITEMS-00000002-00000126=Report2 Number_126.csv
> ITEMS-00000002-00000133=Report2 Number_133.csv
> ITEMS-00000003-00000123=Report3 Number_123.csv
> ITEMS-00000003-00000126=Report3 Number_126.csv
> ITEMS-00000003-00000133=Report3 Number_133.csv
> ```

---

#### Updated Answer (based on the [revised question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561732/5))

After you changed your [original requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561732/2) intensively in the [most recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34561732/5) of your question, I have reworked the script extensively and came up with the following two scripts, each handling a certain name pattern of your `*.csv` report files. Both scripts rely on a temporary file which is used for appropriate sorting using the `sort` command, to get the correct items with the greatest numbers:

1. This script handles all your report files that have a report name, an underscore `_` and an index number in their file names.

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

   rem Set up source and destination directories here:
   set "SOURCE=D:\source"
   set "DESTIN=D:\destin"

   > "%~dpn0.tmp" (
       for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%I in ('
           2^> nul dir /B /A:-D "%SOURCE%\*.csv" ^| ^
           findstr /I /R /C:"^[^_][^_]*_[0-9][0-9]*.csv$"
       ') do (
           set "REPORT=%%I"
           set "NUMBER=00000000000000000000000%%~nJ"
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           echo(!REPORT!^|!NUMBER:~-24!^|!REPORT!_%%J
           endlocal
       )
   )
   set "FORMER="
   < "%~dpn0.tmp" (
       for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=|" %%I in ('
           sort /R
       ') do (
           set "REPORT=%%I"
           set "ORNAME=%%J"
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           if /I not "!REPORT!"=="!FORMER!" (
               > nul copy /Y /B "%SOURCE%\!ORNAME!" "%DESTIN%\!REPORT: =!%%~xJ"
           )
           endlocal
           set "FORMER=%%I"
       )
   )
   del /Q "%~dpn0.tmp"
   endlocal
   exit /B
   ```

   The related temporary file contains the following unsorted data, based on your sample files:

   > ```
   > Call Details Report|000000000001448937644342|Call Details Report_1448937644342.csv
   > Call Details Report|000000000001449662976507|Call Details Report_1449662976507.csv
   > Call Details Report|000000000001450293169999|Call Details Report_1450293169999.csv
   > Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report|000000000001448937621469|Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1448937621469.csv
   > Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report|000000000001449662916869|Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1449662916869.csv
   > Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report|000000000001450293146194|Initial Call Pricing By Archive Report_1450293146194.csv
   > Location Detail Report|000000000001448937658179|Location Detail Report_1448937658179.csv
   > Location Detail Report|000000000001449662949955|Location Detail Report_1449662949955.csv
   > Location Detail Report|000000000001450293201330|Location Detail Report_1450293201330.csv
   > Location Summary Report|000000000001448937672801|Location Summary Report_1448937672801.csv
   > Location Summary Report|000000000001449662994508|Location Summary Report_1449662994508.csv
   > Location Summary Report|000000000001450293231606|Location Summary Report_1450293231606.csv
   > ```

   There data is then sorted with `sort /R`, where `/R` defines reverse sort order. The first `|`-delimited field contains the report name, the second field the zero-padded index number and the third one the original file name. Only such lines are used for copying which hold a report name different to the previous line.
2. This script handles all your report files that have a report name, a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, a `(`, an index number and a `)` in their file names. It even handles files that do not contain an index number but a report name only in their file names, where they are treated as having an index of `0`.

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

   rem Set up source and destination directories here:
   set "SOURCE=D:\source"
   set "DESTIN=D:\destin"

   > "%~dpn0.tmp" (
       for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=()" %%I in ('
           2^> nul dir /B /A:-D "%SOURCE%\*.csv" ^| ^
           findstr /I /R /C:"^[^()]*[^()0-9].csv$" /C:"^[^()][^()]* ([0-9][0-9]*).csv$"
       ') do (
           if "%%J"=="" (
               set "REPORT=%%~nI"
               set "NUMBER=000000000000000000000000"
               setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
               echo(!REPORT!^|!NUMBER:~-24!^|!REPORT!%%~xI
               endlocal
           ) else (
               set "REPORT=%%I"
               set "NUMBER=00000000000000000000000%%J"
               setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
               echo(!REPORT:~,-1!^|!NUMBER:~-24!^|!REPORT!^(%%J^)%%K
               endlocal
           )
       )
   )
   set "FORMER="
   < "%~dpn0.tmp" (
       for /F "tokens=1,3 delims=|" %%I in ('
           sort /R
       ') do (
           set "REPORT=%%I"
           set "ORNAME=%%J"
           setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
           if /I not "!REPORT!"=="!FORMER!" (
               > nul copy /Y /B "%SOURCE%\!ORNAME!" "%DESTIN%\!REPORT: =!%%~xJ"
           )
           endlocal
           set "FORMER=%%I"
       )
   )
   del /Q "%~dpn0.tmp"
   endlocal
   exit /B
   ```

   The related temporary file contains the following unsorted data, based on your sample files:

   > ```
   > Sensor|000000000000000000000001|Sensor (1).csv
   > Sensor|000000000000000000000002|Sensor (2).csv
   > Sensor|000000000000000000000003|Sensor (3).csv
   > StartStop|000000000000000000000001|StartStop (1).csv
   > StartStop|000000000000000000000002|StartStop (2).csv
   > StartStop|000000000000000000000003|StartStop (3).csv
   > StartStop|000000000000000000000000|StartStop.csv
   > ```

   The sorting technique is the same as for the other script.

In order to get all the report files you want, you need to execute both scripts.

Comment: I guess I should have given you guys some more information about exactly how the files are laid out. I updated the main question to give a more accurate listing.  There are 2 different report types. On one the numbers are separated by a "_" and on the other the number is in "( )". I guess I am overthinking things that makes me not understand exactly how to make this work... I will know better next time.. Sorry Guys.

Comment: You changed the requirement with your update; it is unclear how the copied files should be renamed; so please clarify what you need exactly and provide what the copy destination should contain, based on the new data, by editing your question... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off

set max=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%n in ('dir /b Report1*.csv') do (
    if %%n GTR !max! set max=%%n
)
copy "Report1 Number_%max%.csv" otherdir\Report1.csv
```